# Strange behave of index and l3regex

Tags: indexing, latex3, xparse, l3regex

I am experimenting with LaTeX3 features and get a strange behaviour in a combination from `index` and `l3regex`. I try to replace all occurrences of `:<space>` with the exclamation mark sign, so that an entry in the list gets a subentry in the Index.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_demo_tl
\cs_new:Npn \demo #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_demo_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { :\h } {!} \l_demo_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_demo_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\prozessIndex}{m}{\index{\demo{#1}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prozessIndexList}{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\prozessIndex}%
}

\begin{document}
Here some Text
\prozessIndexList{Hello,Hello: World, Muh,Muh!Kuh}    
\printindex
\end{document}
```

But the Result ist

```
Hello!World ,1
Hello , 1
Muh
    Kuh , 1
Muh , 1
```

But it should be

```
Hello , 1
    World , 1
Muh
    Kuh , 1
Muh , 1
```

Is there a other way to go?

Comment: Thank you. I'am here very often. But this is my first question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look in the `.idx` file and you see

```
\indexentry {\demo {Hello}}{1}
\indexentry {\demo {Hello: World}}{1}
\indexentry {\demo {Muh}}{1}
\indexentry {\demo {Muh!Kuh}}{1}
```

You don't want makeindex to see `\demo` but rather the result of running demo so:

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{index}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_demo_tl
\cs_new:Npn \demo #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_demo_tl {#1}
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { :\h } {!} \l_demo_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_demo_tl
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\prozessIndex}{m}{\demo{\index{#1}}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\prozessIndexList}{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\prozessIndex}%
}

\begin{document}
Here some Text
\prozessIndexList{Hello,Hello: World, Muh,Muh!Kuh}    
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Now the idx looks like

```
\indexentry {Hello}{1}
\indexentry {Hello!World}{1}
\indexentry {Muh}{1}
\indexentry {Muh!Kuh}{1}
```

Comment: It work like a charm.

Answer (score 4):

If you replace `index` with `makeidx`, you get several errors about `\h` being an undefined control sequence, which is a hint that something is going wrong; but the main point is that the `.idx` file ends up to contain

```
\indexentry{\tl_set:Nn {Hello}\regex_replace_all:nnN {:}{!}}{1}
\indexentry{\tl_set:Nn {Hello: World}\regex_replace_all:nnN {:}{!}}{1}
\indexentry{\tl_set:Nn {Muh}\regex_replace_all:nnN {:}{!}}{1}
\indexentry{\tl_set:Nn {Muh!Kuh}\regex_replace_all:nnN {:}{!}}{1}
```

which is hardly what you'd like to have. With the `\index` package you'd get

```
\indexentry{\demo {Hello}
```

and so on, so the problem is the same.

You have to do the replacement *before* feeding the word to `\index`. and the normal `xparse` facilities are not sufficient.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}

\makeindex

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\indexlist}{m}
 {% pass control to an internal function
  \landarzar_indexlist:n { #1 }
 }

% two variables
\tl_new:N \l_landarzar_temp_tl
\seq_new:N \l_landarzar_list_seq

% translate `\index` into an internal function
\cs_set_eq:NN \landarzar_index:n \index
% define a variant that uses a value, instead of an explicit argument
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \landarzar_index:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \landarzar_indexlist:n #1
 {
  % split the input into pieces
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_landarzar_list_seq { , } { #1 }
  % process each item in turn
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_landarzar_list_seq
   {
    % pass the item through the regex replacement
    \tl_set:Nn \l_landarzar_temp_tl { ##1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { :\s } { ! } \l_landarzar_temp_tl
    % emit the \index command
    \landarzar_index:V \l_landarzar_temp_tl
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Here some Text
\indexlist{Hello,Hello: World, Muh,Muh!Kuh}    
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Now the `.idx` file reads

```
\indexentry{Hello}{1}
\indexentry{Hello!World}{1}
\indexentry{Muh}{1}
\indexentry{Muh!Kuh}{1}
```

#### Explanation

The argument is split into components using a sequence (which is basically what `\ProcessList` does). Then each item is passed through `\regex_replace_all:nnN` and the correct `\index` command is called, using the *value* of the token list.

#### Note

With `makeidx` or `imakeidx` the `\index` macro does an expansion step of its input, which doesn't happen with the `index` package.

---

A variant code that allows for multiple indices (I use `imakeidx`, but it can be done similarly with `index`). The code is pretty similar, the only relevant difference is how to cope with the optional argument.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{l3regex}
\usepackage{imakeidx}

\makeindex
\makeindex[name=landarzarx]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\indexlist}{O{}m}
 {
  \landarzar_indexlist:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l_landarzar_temp_tl
\seq_new:N \l_landarzar_list_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \landarzar_index:n #1
 {
  \index{#1}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \landarzar_index:nn #1 #2
 {
  \index[#1]{#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \landarzar_index:n { V }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \landarzar_index:nn { nV }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \landarzar_indexlist:nn #1 #2
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_landarzar_list_seq { , } { #2 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_landarzar_list_seq
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_landarzar_temp_tl { ##1 }
    \regex_replace_all:nnN { :\s } { ! } \l_landarzar_temp_tl
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
     { \landarzar_index:V \l_landarzar_temp_tl } % no optional argument
     { \landarzar_index:nV { #1 } \l_landarzar_temp_tl } % optional argument
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
Here some Text

\indexlist{Hello,Hello: World, Muh,Muh!Kuh}
\indexlist[landarzarx]{Hello,Hello: World, Muh,Muh!Kuh}

\printindex
\printindex[landarzarx]

\end{document}
```